# How to make smooth easing for complex path in Anime.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, anime.js

I use Anime.js v 3.2.2.

An object should move by a complex path - an array of {x, y} coordinates.

**The problem**: The "easing" is not applied to the whole animation. Instead easing applies for each "step" from point to point.

**Question**: How to apply easing for whole animation with curved path (more that 2 {x,y} coordinates)?

```js
   // This works well
    anime({
      targets: simpleStateProxy,
      x: 250,
      duration: 1000,
      round: 1,
      easing: 'easeInCubic'
    });
```

```js
//This doesn't work as expected (animation is not smooth, easing is not applied for whole animation
anime({
      targets: complexStateProxy,
      x: [
        { value: 50 },
        { value: 100 },
        { value: 150 },
        { value: 200 },
        { value: 250 },
      ],
      y: [
        { value: 20 },
        { value: 30 },
        { value: 30 },
        { value: 20 },
        { value: 0 },
      ],
      duration: 1000,
      round: 1,
      easing: 'easeInCubic', //
      complete: () => console.log('complex done')
    });
```

Please check code snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s52t17fe/4/).

Thanks.

P.S. If that's not possible in AnimeJS, maybe you could propose any other library which can do that? Preferably with an open license.

P.P.S: a link to the [issue](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/702) on github.

```js
const simple = document.getElementById('simple');
const complex = document.getElementById('complex');

const simpleState = { x: 0, y: 0 }  //x - left, y - top
const complexState = { x: 0, y: 0 }  //x - left, y - top

// do not pay attention to this
const simpleStateProxy = new Proxy(simpleState, {
  set: (target, key, value) => {
    target[key] = value;
    simple.style.left = `${value}px`;
    return true;
  },
});

// do not pay attention to this
const complexStateProxy = new Proxy(complexState, {
  set: (target, key, value) => {
    target[key] = value;
    if (key === 'x') complex.style.left = `${value}px`;
    if (key === 'y') complex.style.top = `${value}px`;
    return true;
  },
});


// Animation of a "simple" box
anime({
  targets: simpleStateProxy,
  x: 250,
  duration: 1000,
  round: 1,
  easing: 'easeInCubic',
  complete: () => console.log('simple done')
});

// Animation of a "complex" box
anime({
  targets: complexStateProxy,
  x: [
    { value: 50 },
    { value: 100 },
    { value: 150 },
    { value: 200 },
    { value: 250 },
  ],
  y: [
    { value: 20 },
    { value: 30 },
    { value: 30 },
    { value: 20 },
    { value: 0 },
  ],
  duration: 1000,
  round: 1,
  easing: 'easeInCubic',
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container:last-of-type {
  top: 60px;
}


.box {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="simple" class="box">simple</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="complex" class="box">complex</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Dec 2023**: There is a workaround how to do that in v3: you can create 2 animations: the first animation with `autoplay: false` and `easing: linear`, and the second one with the easing you want that controls the progress of the first animation. ([based on this answer](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/702#issuecomment-1865015595)).

```js
const path = [
  { x: 50, y: 30 },
  { x: 100, y: 45 },
  { x: 150, y: 55 },
  { x: 200, y: 45 },
  { x: 250, y: 0 },
];

const duration = 1000;

const baseAnimation = anime({
  targets: yourTarget, 
  x: path.map(p => p.x),
  y: path.map(p => p.y),
  easing: 'linear',
  autoplay: false,
  duration 
});

anime({
  targets: baseAnimation,
  progress: [0, 100], 
  easing: 'easeInCubic',
  duration,
  update: (anim) => {
    baseAnimation.seek(baseAnimation.duration * (baseAnimation.progress / 100));
  }
});
```

([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t3dhs9c/1/))

===========================

Old answer:

After some research I found out that it's **probably not possible with Animejs** (at least version 3).

At the moment of posting (dec 2023) the related [issue](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/702) is still open and unattended.

Here is examples how to achieve that with some other libs:

- with motion.dev: [[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sandpack-project-forked-z4c9vh?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A10%2C19)];
- with GSAP: [[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sandpack-project-forked-h9vldw?file=%2Findex.html)];

P.S. Pay attention that [GSAP](https://gsap.com/) is not free for commercial usage, and [motion.dev](https://motion.dev/) is feels a bit abandoned, so I hardly can recommend both.